# Swift - Programmatically change the barButtonSystemItem of an IBOutlet

Tags: swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

In `Swift`, I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that have been created in a `xib` file and calls the `play` function on click.

```
@IBOutlet var btnPlay: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func play(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

how to change the  `barButtonSystemItem` in the function `play`?